# extracting the output using python

Tags: python

How do i extract the required data from the output  and save it to a variable

**this is my program:**

```
import commands

cmd = curl -v -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET -u hitman:hitman <https://test.com:8181/v1/config/sipregistrar

result = commands.getoutput(cmd)
print result
```

now run the programm :

python test25.py

**output :**

```
About to connect() to test.com port 8181 (#0)
Trying test.com...   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0connected
Connected to 50.50.50.201 (50.50.50.201) port 8181 (#0)
successfully set certificate verify locations:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 05 Jun 2012 18:27:11 GMT
Server: Jetty(6.1.22)
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=12buplms5odzt;Path=/config
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Closing connection #0
 SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
} [data not shown]
{"sip_domains":{"prefix":[{"name":""}],"domain":[{"name":"k200.com"},{"name":"zinga.com"},{"name":"rambo.com"}]},"sip_security":{"level":2},"sip_trusted_hosts":{"host":[]},"sip_proxy_mode":{"handle_requests":1}}
```

from this output , the params i require :

> {"sip_domains":{"prefix":[{"name":""}],"domain":[{"name":"k200.com"},{"name":"zinga.com"},{"name":"rambo.com"}]},"sip_security":{"level":2},"sip_trusted_hosts":{"host":[]},"sip_proxy_mode":{"handle_requests":1}}

How do i extract the above and save it to a variable ?

Comment: Please, read the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and edit your question. It's unreadable like this.

Comment: +1 for welcome to StackOverflow, anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have cleaned this up, removed `eval`, and converted the result using JSON, to make it safe:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

output = '''[data extract]Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=12buplms5odzt;Path=/config
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Closing connection #0
 SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
} [data not shown]
{"sip_domains":{"prefix":[{"name":""}],"domain":[{"name":"k200.com"},{"name":"zinga.com"},{"name":"rambo.com"}]},"sip_security":{"level":2},"sip_trusted_hosts":{"host":[]},"sip_proxy_mode":{"handle_requests":1}}'''

output = json.loads( output.split("\n")[-1] )

pprint( output )
```

The variable `output` now contains this dictionary:

```
{'sip_domains': {'domain': [{'name': 'k200.com'},
                            {'name': 'zinga.com'},
                            {'name': 'rambo.com'}],
                 'prefix': [{'name': ''}]},
 'sip_proxy_mode': {'handle_requests': 1},
 'sip_security': {'level': 2},
 'sip_trusted_hosts': {'host': []}}
```

This is simply an alternative, and @jcfollower has a +1 from me for a succinct and effective solution.

Comment: output = eval( result.split("\n")[-1] )
print output

json_dict = json.loads(output)
print json_dict

for domain_dict in json_dict['sip_domains']['domain']:

        print  'domain : %s' % (domain_dict['name'])

Comment: {'sip_domains': {'prefix': [{'name': ''}], 'domain': [{'name': 'k200.com'}, {'name': 'cucm.com'}]}, 'sip_proxy_mode': {'handle_requests': 1}, 'sip_security': {'level': 2}, 'sip_trusted_hosts': {'host': []}}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test25.py", line 34, in <module>
    json_dict = json.loads(output)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loadsreturn _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 360, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
getting this error ... ???

Comment: Sorry, I was out of network for a while. You were not supposed to load it as a JSON string. Just a `print output` would have been enough. Anyway, with either version, note that if you do not trust where the data is coming from, `eval()` would be a security hole so I did this just for fun... If you want to use the JSON, then do `output = output.split("\n")[-1]`

Answer (score 2):

If you just need a string of those params and all your output always follows that pattern and nothing in your [data not shown] sabotages this, you could try ...

```
params = results[results.find('{"'):]
```

That takes the portion of results that starts at {"sip_domains"
If you end up having another {" before hand, though, this will break.